# How to pass generics using wildcard to a function without casting?

Tags: java, generics, bounded-wildcard

Here is my problem:
my function in class A:

```
public void setData(Map<String,? extends ArrayList<? extends SomeInterface>>){...}
```

my call:

```
Map<String, ArrayList<ImplementsSomeInterface>> a=...;
instanceOfA.setData(a); //does not compile
instanceOfA.setData((Map<String,? extends ArrayList<? extends SomeInterface>>) a); // works thanks to the Casting.
```

I don't think this is clean. Is there a way to avoid the casting without droping the wildcard use in the function?

Comment: Is class A generic? What does class A declaration look like?

Comment: What do you mean it works? No ClassCastException when running it? What is subClassOfSomeClass?

Comment: If `subClassOfSomeClass` is not an ArrayList of anything, how can this work?

Comment: ... and `subClassOfSomeClass` is or isn't a subclass of `ArrayList`? Because that's your type bound.

Comment: ooops sorry, I didn't see your comments while I was updating my question!

Comment: @claesv A is just a normal Class, I don't think it affects the rest of the code

Comment: @assylias no it works as though I wasn't using the wildcards

Comment: @sinelaw you're right forgot the ArrayList..

Comment: you guys are too fast! It'll teach me to fully check my questions in the future. Thank you!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First your `setData` method should read:

```
public void setData(Map<String,? extends List<? extends SomeInterface>>)
```

Your map declaration should read:

```
Map<String, List<ImplementsSomeInterface>> a = ...;
```

Which is pretty much what you've got following your edits to the original question.  The change I've made from `ArrayList` to `List` doesn't effect the behaviour of the code.

**Following comments:**

```
public static void main() 
{
    Map<String, List<Double>> map = new HashMap<String, List<Double>>();
    map.put("prices", new ArrayList<Double>(Arrays.asList(1.1, 2.2, 3.3)));

    setData(map);
}

public static void setData(Map<String,? extends List<? extends Serializable>> map)      
{
}
```

Comment: assuming I use `public void setData(Map<String,? extends List<? extends SomeClass>>)` I still have to cast the parameter in the call as follow `instanceOfA.setData((Map<String,? extends ArrayList<? extends SomeInterface>>) a);` is there a way to avoid the casting?

Comment: Not in the version of Java 1.6 I'm using, I tried it :-)  I'll add the code to my answer.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that setData takes as an argument a 
`Map<String,? extends ArrayList<? extends SomeClass>>`Map>
whereas in your first call(the one that doesn't compile) you are trying to pass it a `Map<String,? extends SomeClass>`

Java cannot automatically cast a subclass of 
`SomeClass`
to a subclass of 
`ArrayList<? extends SomeClass>`
because it is not neccesarily an instance of ArrayList.